# How to make copy of RestTemplateBuilder?

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I would like to have one base configuration for all my `RestTemplate` instances.

I've created `RestTemplateProvider` that gets `RestTemplateBuilder` from Spring Boot and sets appropriate timeouts and other options.

Question is - how I can clone `RestTemplateBuilder` in order to prevent its modifications from places where it's used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the sources for [`RestTemplateBuilder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.java#L148) you will notice that each time a setting is changed a new instance of `RestTemplateBuilder` is being created.

So what you want is basically already baked into the `RestTemplateBuilder` itself out-of-the-box.

Comment: Also note that the Javadocs for those methods say `@return a new builder instance`.